# Is there a string size limit when feeding .fromstring() method as input?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I'm working on multiple well-formed xml files, whose sizes range from 100 MB to 4 GB. My goal is to read them as strings and then import them as ElementTree objects using .fromstring() method (from xml.etree.ElementTree module).
However, as the process goes through and the string size increases, two exceptions occured related to memory restriction :

- **xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: out of memory: line 1, column 0**
- **OverflowError: size does not fit in an int**

It looks like **.fromstring() method enforces a string size limit to the input**, around 1GB... ?
To debug this, I wrote a short script using a for loop:

```
xmlFiles_list = [path1, path2, ...]
for fp in xmlFiles_list:
    xml_fo = open(fp, mode='r', encoding="utf-8")
    xml_asStr = xml_fo.read()
    xml_fo.close()

    print(len(xml_asStr.encode("utf-8")) / 10**9) # display string size in GB
    
    try:
        etree = cElementTree.fromstring(xml_asStr)
        print(".fromstring() success!\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error :{type(e)} {str(e)}\n")
        continue
```

The ouput is as following :

```
0.895206753
.fromstring() success!

1.220224531
Error :<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError'> out of memory: line 1, column 0

1.328233473
Erreur :<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError'> out of memory: line 1, column 0

2.567867904
Error :<class 'OverflowError'> size does not fit in an int

4.080672538
Error :<class 'OverflowError'> size does not fit in an int
```

---

I found multiple workarounds to avoid this issue : .parse() method or lxml module for bette performance. I just hope someone could shed some light on this :

- Is there a specific string size limit in xml.etree.ET module and .fromstring() method ?
- Why do I end up with two different exceptions as the string size increases ? Are they related to the same memory-allocation restriction ?

Python version/system: 3.9 (64 bits)
RAM : 32go

Hope my topic is clear enough, I'm new on stackoverflow

Comment: *"My goal is to read them as strings and then import them as ElementTree objects using .fromstring() "* - That's not wise for files of this size. Why would you want to do it that way? (It's also not wise **in general**. If you have files, *always* use `.parse('filename')`, never `open()` and `.fromstring()`).

Comment: Some xml on which I work might have invalid tokens such as hexadecimal NCR (ex : `&#x11`). `parse` does not work in that case and in the context of using only `xml.etree.ElementTree`, the only solution I found is `open()` then `.fromstring()`. Besides, i ask this just for my own understanding.

Comment: What's the XML version in the XML declaration? `<?xml version="1.1">`, by any chance?

Comment: All files have the xml declaration : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: In that case the files were created by something that was not XML aware. All bets are off what else is wrong with them, because things like `&#x11;` are illegal in XML 1.0. But assuming `&#x11;` was your only problem, I would *still* recommend an iterative parser (i.e. `.iterparse()`). Wrap the file in a filter that replaces the offending sequences as the file is read. Don't attempt to load everything at once, that's not a good approach even if you have enough RAM for it.

Comment: All right. Thanks @Tomalak. Still do you have any explanations or sources about my two questions ?

Comment: No. I tend to avoid doing unwise things, if I can at all help it. ;) Python is open-source, you can at least in theory answer your question by taking a look.